# How to store value in object Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price, object-manager, object

How do you change **price** in the frontend without affecting database. I have found the following code for it, but now I want to set my **custom price** in object.

```
Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\Base Object
(
    [amount:protected] => 36
    [baseAmount:protected] => 
    [totalAdjustmentAmount:protected] => 
    [adjustmentAmounts:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [adjustments:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I want to change amount value programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The price on a product can be set by calling the following two methods:

```
$product->setPriceCalculation(false);
$product->setPrice($priceValue);
```

This will update the price on the product, but the price will not be persisted to the database. This is because Magento 2, similar to Magento 1, uses pricing models to calculate price data. If the price is set on the product in Magento 1, that value will be used instead of requesting the price from the price model. In Magento 2, there was a change made:

```
//From \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product

public function getPrice()
{
    if ($this->_calculatePrice || !$this->getData(self::PRICE)) {
        return $this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this);
    } else {
        return $this->getData(self::PRICE);
    }
}
```

Notice how if the `_calculatePrice` property is set to true, it will always recalculate the price from the price model? This is new behavior in Magento 2. By default, it is true, and thus recalculate every time.

Please let me know if you have any other questions!